Как добавить в выпадающий список (в классическом редакторе wordpress) свои кнопки \ пресеты?
Всем привет. Я нашел способ как добавить просто кнопки (в редакторе html, в визуальном редакторе). А как добавить их в уже созданный (дефолтный выпадающий список wp tinymce) свои прессеты ?
Добавление в режиме html редактора
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'theme_add_quicktags', 99 );
function theme_add_quicktags() {
    if ( ! wp_script_is('quicktags') )
        return;

    ?>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        QTags.addButton( 'r4_div_blue', 'div_blue', '<div class="color-blue">', '</div>', 'd', 'Div blue', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'r4_h3_blue', 'h3_blue', '<h3 class="color-blue">', '</h3>', 'h', 'H3 blue', 2 );
        QTags.addButton( 'r4_ol_lg', 'ol_lg', '<ol class="lg-list">', '</ol>', 'o', 'Ol lg', 3 );
        
    } );
    </script>
    <?php
}
//QTags.addButton( id, display, arg1, arg2, access_key, title, priority, instance );

Добавление в режиме визуального редактора (кнопки )
tinymce-buttons.js
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.theme_buttons', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('r4_div_blue', {
                title : 'Div blue',
                icon: 'mce-ico mce-i-checkmark', // использование иконки Dashicons
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<div class="color-blue"></div>');
                    ed.label = 'Div blue';
                }
            });
            ed.addButton('r4_h3_blue', {
                title : 'H3 blue',
                icon: 'mce-ico mce-i-checkmark', // использование иконки Dashicons
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<h3 class="color-blue"></h3>');
                    ed.label = 'H3 blue';
                }
            });
            ed.addButton('r4_ol_lg', {
                title : 'Ol lg',
                icon: 'mce-ico mce-i-checkmark', // использование иконки Dashicons
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<ol class="lg-list"><li></li></ol>');
                    ed.label = 'Ol lg';
                }
            });
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('theme_buttons', tinymce.plugins.theme_buttons);
})();

function.php
function theme_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['theme_buttons'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/tinymce-buttons.js?v=17'; // путь к вашему JS файлу
    return $plugin_array;
}

function theme_register_buttons($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, 'r4_div_blue', 'r4_h3_blue', 'r4_ol_lg');
    return $buttons;
}


Для добавления своих пресетов в выпадающий список TinyMCE в WordPress, вам нужно будет использовать фильтры и действия, предоставляемые TinyMCE. Вот пример, как это можно сделать:

Создайте файл JavaScript для вашего плагина TinyMCE:

Создайте файл tinymce-presets.js в вашей теме или плагине. В этом файле вы будете добавлять свои пресеты.


(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.theme_presets', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            // Добавляем новый выпадающий список
            ed.addButton('theme_presets', {
                type: 'listbox',
                text: 'Presets',
                icon: false,
                onselect: function(e) {
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, this.value());
                },
                values: [
                    {text: 'Div blue', value: '<div class="color-blue"></div>'},
                    {text: 'H3 blue', value: '<h3 class="color-blue"></h3>'},
                    {text: 'Ol lg', value: '<ol class="lg-list"><li></li></ol>'}
                ],
                onPostRender: function() {
                    // Устанавливаем значение по умолчанию
                    this.value('');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('theme_presets', tinymce.plugins.theme_presets);
})();




Добавьте фильтры и действия в functions.php вашей темы:



function theme_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['theme_presets'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/tinymce-presets.js?v=17'; // путь к вашему JS файлу
    return $plugin_array;
}
add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'theme_tinymce_plugin');

function theme_register_buttons($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, 'theme_presets');
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'theme_register_buttons');




Добавьте стили для ваших пресетов (если необходимо):

Если вам нужно добавить стили для ваших пресетов, вы можете добавить их в CSS файл вашей темы или плагина.


.color-blue {
    color: blue;
}
.lg-list {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}



Теперь, когда вы откроете визуальный редактор TinyMCE, у вас будет новый выпадающий список с вашими пресетами. Вы можете выбрать любой из них, и соответствующий HTML-код будет вставлен в редактор.
